# Converting strings to a lower case in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, lowercase

I have a data that contains domain names:

```
 url          var1
www.CNN.com   xsd
www.Nbc.com   wer
www.BBc.com   xyz
www.fOX.com   zyx
....
```

The data is of the Series type. I am using the following to convert url variable to lower case:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

However, they remain the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 53):

```
df['url'] = df['url'].str.lower()
```

should operate on the series and replace it with the lower case version.

Comment: got an error `//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  app.launch_new_instance()`

Comment: @FeyziBagirov I didn't get that in my test data set that I tried to mirror yours (also python 3.5).  Can you post code in your question for generating the data set just so we have the same input?

Comment: @FeyziBagirov you may try `df['url'] = df.loc[:,'url'].str.lower()` but I concur with David it's unnecessary here

Comment: @FeyziBagirov: for me syntax like: `df.loc[:, 'url'] = df.loc[:, 'url'].str.lower()` finally worked.

Answer (score 10):

To convert a single column we can use,

```
df.column_name.str.lower()
```

or

```
df['column_name'].str.lower()
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 9):

I think you need assign output back, better is omit `apply` if works only with column `url`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['www.CNN.com', 'www.Nbc.com', 'www.BBc.com', 'www.fOX.com'], 
                   'var1': ['XSD', 'wer', 'xyz', 'zyx']})

print (df)
           url var1
0  www.CNN.com  XSD
1  www.Nbc.com  wer
2  www.BBc.com  xyz
3  www.fOX.com  zyx

#if types of column is str, astype is not necessary
df.url = df.url.astype(str).str.lower()
print (df)
           url var1
0  www.cnn.com  XSD
1  www.nbc.com  wer
2  www.bbc.com  xyz
3  www.fox.com  zyx
```

But if need convert all columns of `df` to `lowercase string`s:

```
df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
print (df)
           url var1
0  www.cnn.com  xsd
1  www.nbc.com  wer
2  www.bbc.com  xyz
3  www.fox.com  zyx
```

Comment: The first solution generated an error `//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2701: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self[name] = value` The second solution works though

Comment: I think problem is in code above this row, can you share 2,3 rows above?

Comment: Or maybe check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: I add test sample, do you have error with it?