# How to lowercase text between two string

Tags: lowercase

I have this code:

```
<Layer Idx="2" Name="scr FILI FISSI SOLAIO">
<Layer Idx="2" Name="scr FILI ALTRO">
<Layer Idx="2" Name="scr PIPPO">
```

I want to convert in lowercase the text between (") or other string:

```
<Layer Idx="2" Name="scr fili fissi solaio">
<Layer Idx="2" Name="scr fili altro">
<Layer Idx="2" Name="scr pippo">
```

Comment: I would like to share a link if this helps. [Pandas lower case string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750551/converting-strings-to-a-lower-case-in-pandas)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I use Sublime text.
I would like to use the command search and replace