# Standardizing tags to be one hot encoded

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification

I have data that is pulled from the Petfinder API and there is a field called tags that has a list of adjectives. I'm using MultiLabelBinarizer to one hot encode the adjectives for a model. The problem I'm running into is there are duplicates of certain words, like 'loving', 'sweet', 'happy', etc. However, the casing treats it as two different words.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
enc = MultiLabelBinarizer() #initialize 
enc.fit(df["tags"]) #fitting
tag = enc.transform(df["tags"]) #transform fit 
tclass = enc.classes_ #stores each column list
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=tag, columns=tclass)
sum_column = df2.sum(axis=0)
print(sum_column)
```

| sweet | loving | happy | playful | Sweet | Loving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

For this example I would keep the lowercase column for 'sweet' and records tagged as 'Sweet' would be one hot encoded under 'sweet'.

Is there a way to combine the tags/columns or standardize the case before it's one hot encoded?

**EDIT:**
Before the data is one-hot encoded this is how the [field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L29CS.png) looks like. Since it's a tag there are brackets around it. I've tried playing around with it and I was able to remove the brackets using `df["tags"] = df["tags"].str.join(',')`. However, I want to create consistency in the adjectives. For example in some instances, the word sweet is lowercase while the rest are uppercase. The description 'Easy going' has a space when other records tag it as one word. The red underline in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L29CS.png) is what I want to correct uniformly across all records and green is the general form I'd like for it to follow. That way in the table above there would only be one sweet column and one loving column

| sweet | loving | happy | playful |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Have you tried [converting the strings to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750551/converting-strings-to-a-lower-case-in-pandas)?

Comment: Before it's one-hot encoded the values are in a list that was bracketed. I was able to remove the brackets using `df["tags"] = df["tags"].str.join(',')`. When apply the string converter to the field using `df['tags'] = df['tags'].str.lower` I get `<bound method StringMethods.lower of <pandas.c...`

Comment: Instead of `df['tags'].str.lower`, you  should use `df['tags'].str.lower()`.